Sum Bottom of Column(s) with Dynamic Formula
I am working on a vba code that places the sum of a column (F) dynamically at the bottom. I would like this formula to loop through the remaining columns in the worksheet up to column AM (e.g. columns G, H, I etc.)  How do you suppose I do this?
This is my code:
Sub SumColumns()
    Dim LastRows As Long
    
    Lastrows = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f" & Lastrows + 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("f5:f" & Lastrows - 1))
    
End Sub


This code sums only if the column has any data in it and place the result in the second cell to the bottom of the column's data.
Sub col_sum()
Dim cols As Range
Set cols = ActiveSheet.Columns("F:AM")  'the columns to sum

For Each colu In cols.Columns
  lastr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colu.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, colu.Column)) And lastr = 1 Then
  Else
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lastr + 2, colu.Column) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(colu)
  End If
Next colu

End Sub



Hi BlackCat, I like your code.  Sorry, I forgot to mention that I have a subtotal in the last row.  How do I exclude this from the sum?  Is it just .End(xlup).Row -1?  This way the sum is not duplicated.

That wouldn't return the right value since Sum function should be modified. I suggest to subtract the last value like this = WorksheetFunction.Sum(colu) - Cells(lastr, colu.Column)

Add Totals Row


This should be mimicking your code's behavior.

Sub AddTotalsRow()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "E5"
    ' the row offset from the last cell in column 'E' to the last cells
    ' in the sum columns?
    Const SRC_LAST_ROW_OFFSET As Long = -2
    ' the row offset from the last cell in column 'E' to the totals row?
    Const TOTALS_ROW_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const DST_COLUMNS As String = "F:AM"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(SRC_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        RowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If RowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data in column
        Set srg = .Resize(RowsCount)
    End With

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMNS)
    
    Dim dFirstColumnAddress As String: dFirstColumnAddress = drg _
        .Columns(1).Resize(RowsCount + SRC_LAST_ROW_OFFSET).Address(0, 0)
    
    With drg.Rows(RowsCount).Offset(TOTALS_ROW_OFFSET)
        .Formula = "=SUM(" & dFirstColumnAddress & ")" ' write formula
        ' Adjust 'TOTALS_ROW_OFFSET' making sure the formulas' row is correct!
        ' Adjust 'SRC_LAST_ROW_OFFSET' making sure the formulas are correct!
        ' Only then uncomment the following line to convert to values.
        '.Value = .Value ' convert to values
    End With
    
End Sub

